# Amazon CloudWatch Logs Insights: Aggregating logs using bin(1w) always starts on a Sunday

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I want to display a bar diagram where each bar represents a week starting on a Monday.
The below meta code does that except that each week starts on a Sunday.

I realize that the [Query syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html) only mentions time periods with *m* for minutes and *h* for hours, but it seems to work fine also using *d* for day and *w* for week (except that I cannot set the starting day).

Any idea how to make weeks starting on Mondays instead of Sundays?

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| fields strcontains(@message, 'the start') as start
| fields strcontains(@message, 'the result') as result
| stats sum(start) as startCalls, sum(result) as resultCalls by bin(1w) as t
| sort t asc
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will work: "fromMillis(toMillis(bin(1w))+86400000) as Week"